# Switch between layers - Android StudiO Editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Stupid question..
I can't find any options within the editor or online regarding this matter.

Q. How can i easily switch between for example a Textview which matches both width and height of a layout and the layout behind the textview in Android Studio Editor?

Answer (score 0):

Alright found what i was looking for.

"Component Tree"